Multer in node.js not returning a readable upload into backend folders/files
I am currently using multer to submit a profile picture to the folder "pfps" for a school assignment, which should create a file that is the same as the front-end. However, it creates a file of random text characters with no .png or .jpg ending tag and cannot be read.
My code in the backend javascript currently is
const express = require("express");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database(".database/user.db")
var fs = require('fs');
const cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'myPWA/pfps')
    },
    filenane: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({ dest: "/pfps" });

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "myPWA")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "myPWA/index.html"));
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
    }),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, "myPWA"))
)

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
})

and the html for the form is
<div class="page-content">
    <form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar"/>
        <button type="submit">upload</button>
    </form>
</div>

Which should return some file in the backend files like
this
However, it returns a file like this.
Also, when I tried to log the file,
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);

it returns
[Object: null prototype] {}
undefined

however I have looked online and it returns something like this
Does anybody have a solution??
Thanks in advance.

It might be because of the typo in your backend:
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'myPWA/pfps')
    },
    filenane: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

correct "filenane" to "filename".
Hope it helps.

TYSM i couldn't figure it out
